# Is Yield Return == IEnumerable & IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield, iterator, ienumerator

Is `yield return` a shortcut for implementing `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, it is.

You can find out a lot more about it in chapter 6 of my book, C# in Depth. Fortunately chapter 6 is [available for free](http://www.manning-source.com/books/skeet/Chapter6sample.pdf) from [Manning's web site](http://manning.com/skeet/).

I also have two [other](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx) [articles](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx) on the book's web site.

Feedback welcome.

Comment: Great book! I'm actually on chapter 6, wasn't expecting an answer from the author!!! ;)

Comment: The chapter link redirects to the site's root, you can go straight to the C# in Depth page here: http://www.manning.com/skeet/

Comment: The articles have a lot of details. Thanks for pointing them.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the link-fest, Raymond Chen did a nice little series on C# iterators a few months ago:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/12/8849519.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/13/8854601.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/14/8862242.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/15/8868267.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  See the following for a starter

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx