# How do interfaces like IEnumerable work without proper implementation?

Tags: c#, interface, ienumerable

From what I understand on interfaces, is that in order to use them, you must declare that a class is implementing it by adding the name of the interface after a colon and then, implement the methods.

I'm currently learning about Enumerators, IEnumerable etc. and this got me confused. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
static IEnumerable<int> Fibs(int fibCount)
{
    for (int i = 0, prevFib = 1, curFib = 1; i < fibCount; i++) {
        yield return prevFib;
        int newFib = prevFib + curFib;
        prevFib = curFib;
        curFib = newFib;
    }
}
```

IEnumerable seems to be a normal interface as any other, I even checked the method definition and that's what it pretty much seems like.

How is it possible that I can use an interface as a type/return type in the method definition and when/how do I know I should use certain interfaces as types like in this example?

EDIT: I really doubt it has anything to do with the yield keyword since a lot of interfaces are used as properties this way for example in MVC in Models and passed like it to Views. Example:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Categories {get;set;}
```

Comment: `yield return` is magic. It returns an `IEnumerable` of the type after the `return` statement.

Comment: Here's a few questions on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317462/some-help-understanding-yield  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288808/is-yield-return-ienumerable-ienumerator  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39476/what-is-the-yield-keyword-used-for-in-c  The `Task`/`Task<T>` classes also have special compiler support so that `async`/`await` can be implemented by constructing a (hidden) state machine that is very similar to the one created for the `yield` keyword.

Comment: @Andrew B: your second example -- a property with an interface type, is completely different from your first. You can use interfaces as properties, parameters, return types, etc. whenever you want, as long as when you go to *set* the property or *return* a value, you have a concrete implementation to work with. `yield` is special because it creates the concrete implementation for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEnumerable is a special case. The [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) return statement instructs the compiler to add the code that implements IEnumerable.

As for **your edit**:
If an interface is used a the type of a property, any object of a class that implements this interface can be assigned and the property will return an object that implements this interface. In your example, any collection of categories that implements `IEnumerable<Category>` can be assigned to the property, e.g. a `List<Category>`. In comparison to using just `List<Category>`, using the interface allows a wider range of objects to be assigned. The interface defines the abstract requirements that are relevant for the property.

Answer (score 6):

There is extra magic when you use [`yield` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx), i.e. create an iterator block. The compiler makes a state machine for you.

So C# has a special feature here, and it only has this feature with `IEnumerable<>`. So it is the C# language which is magical.

The interface `IEnumerable<>` in itself is a boring ordinary type. No magic in it.

Note: Technically, the `yield` magic works when the "formal" return type is either `IEnumerable<>`, `IEnumerator<>`, `IEnumerable`, or `IEnumerator`, but usually you use the first of these. Do not go non-generic, of course.

Comment: Well I've seen this being used in MVC numerous times in order to pass lists with IEnumerable and IList etc. which definitely didn't have anything to do with the yield keyword... For example as a property in a Model?

Comment: @AndrewB : so where did these `IEnumerable` interfaces come from? From objects that implement `IEnumerable`, for sure. The Model property is just set in controller (by you, the dev)... the source could be a method with yield return, or an object that implements IEnumerable... such as those returned from linq statements, for instance.

Comment: @spender , Hmm... So should I consider these 2 occasions "wildcards" of sorts? The yield keyword and the few times I use IEnumberable, IList etc. in the MVC pattern?

Comment: @AndrewB: If you declare an IEnumerable parameter in ASP.NET MVC, the model binder will automatically use a `List`, which implements `IEnumerable`. If you're calling methods that return an `IEnumerable`, they will return some class that implements the `IEnumerable` interface--often this is a `List`, but it can be one of various other types as well. Methods with `yield return` in them get compiled to return a special, custom-generated class that implements the `IEnumerable` interface.

Comment: Might be worth explaining what the magic is really about - and it's saving and restoring the state of a method during execution, as described at msdn.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, interfaces are a special "kind" of type that differs from a class in a few key ways:

- You cannot include any implementation code of their methods.
- A single class can "inherit from" (called "implementing") as many as it wants.
- You cannot instantiate a `new` instance of an interface.

(There is also some language features associated specifically with interfaces, such as explicit implementations, but those aren't important for this discussion.)

Beyond that, interfaces can be use pretty much anywhere you can use any other reference type. That includes defining fields, properties, or local variables with interface types, or using them as parameter types or return types on methods.

The trick is, if you define a property as, say, an `IEnumerable<int>`, and you want to set it's value, you cannot do this:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Numbers { get; set; }
...
this.Numbers = new IEnumerable<int>();
```

That's an error. You can't create a new instance of an interface, because it's just a "template" -- there's nothing "behind" it to actually do anything. However, you *can* do this:

```
public IEnumerable<int> Numbers { get; set; }
...
this.Numbers = new List<int>();
```

Because `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, the compiler will automatically do the type conversion to make the assignment work. Any concrete class that implements `IEnumerable<>` can be assigned to a property of type `IEnumerable<>`, which is why you see interface property types so often. It allows you to change the underlying concrete type (maybe you want to change `List<T>` to `ObservableCollection<T>`, but the users of your class neither know nor care when you do.

The same goes for methods with an interface return type, except there's an extra option here that C# throws in as a bonus:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetName()
{
    // this fails.
    return new IEnumerable<string>();

    // this works.
    return new List<String>();

    // this also works because magic!~
    yield return "hello";
    yield return "there";
    yield return "!";
}
```

That last case is a special form of "syntactic sugar" that C# provides because it's such a common requirement. As other people have mentioned, the compiler specifically looks for `yield return` statements on methods that return `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator` (both generic and non-generic versions) and does some hefty rewriting of the code.

Behind the scenes, C# is creating a hidden class, which implements `IEnumerable<string>`, and implementing it's `GetEnumerator` method to return an `IEnumerator<string>` object that provides those three string values. That would be a lot of boilerplate code for you to write, although you could certainly write it yourself. In previous versions of C#, there was no `yield` and you did have to write it yourself.

If you really want to know, you can find the C# equivalent [here](http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/index.php?title=CSharp_Coding_Solutions%E2%80%94What_Does_Yield_Keyword_Generate), among other places. In essence, it takes the method that contains your `yield` statements and creates a `IEnumerator<>.MoveNext` method out of it, but turning it into a state machine. It uses the equivalent of labels and goto statements to jump back to the correct place each time a consumer calls `MoveNext` on the same instance. Also, as I understand it, it does things that you can't actually do in C# (it jumps into and out of loops) but that are legal in IL code, so it's implementation is more efficient that what you could write yourself.

But once you get past the secret cause of the `yield` keyword, you're still doing the same thing. You're still creating a class, that implements `IEnumerable<>`, and using that as the return value for your method.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, even though the method return type is `IEnumerable<int>`, the actual return type will be a type that implements `IEnumerable<int>`.  As others have mentioned, the ‘yield return’ results in a type which implements `IEnumerable<int>`.  In this specific case, you don’t know what that type is.  When I run this through the debugger and do a `result.GetType()` (where `result` is returned from the `Fibs` method), I see that `result` is of type `<Fibs>d__0`, which sounds a little strange to me.  So instead of worrying about that strange-sounding type, we can just treat it like an `IEnumerable<int>`, because all we really want to be able to do is to iterate over it, which is the behavior that `IEnumerable<int>` exposes.

That’s for your specific example, but the idea is the same elsewhere.  By using an interface, you are saying that you don’t care exactly what type is used/returned, as long as it exposes certain behavior or properties.  For example if I have an interface `IFoo` that exposes a method `DoSomething()`, and I have a method that returns `IFoo`, then I can return anything that implements `IFoo`, but no matter what I return, the caller of the method is sure that it can `DoSomething()` with the object.  Similarly, if I have a method that takes an `IFoo`, then the method is sure that it will be able to `DoSomething()` with that parameter.

For me interfaces also help me design my classes.  For example I write the interface first to determine what’s important for the class to be able to do and have, and then I create the concrete class that implements that interface.  And when I’m writing code that uses the class, I ask for the interface rather than the concrete type.

And there’s all sorts of other reasons to use interfaces, for example to create mocks for testing, for dependency injection, for fluent API design, and probably a hundred other reasons.